# Does creating an instance variable that is set to be a new object inside a method save memory over creating a local variable inside the method?

Tags: java

I think this question is a bit confusing without looking at any code, so here is my example:

This:

```
public class Example {

    public Object foo() {
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

vs this:

```
public class Example {

    private Object object;

    public Object foo() {
        object = new Object();
        return object;
    }
}
```

Does the 2nd example just switch the memory address of the instance variable and not create a new one? Does doing it the 2nd way save memory?

The reason I ask is because the method could very likely be called *very many times* during the runtime of the program.

Thanks!

Comment: In your example, neither approach is going to save you much memory, as you are constantly creating a new instance of the object regardless, so there is no advantage

Comment: I don't have a concrete answer for you off the top of my head, but in general, for questions like these it'd be best to take a look at the compiled bytecode to see what, if any, the difference is.

Comment: No it won't save you any memory, and it will also create a concurrency problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the 2nd example just switch the memory address of the instance
>   variable and not create a new one? Does doing it the 2nd way save
>   memory?

No, the new instance will be created in a new location in memory.

The existing memory will not be available until garbage collection has determined there are no references to the existing instance.

Comment: Thank you, that's all I needed to know!

Answer (score 1):

Does it save memory? No, it uses more memory. Because now every instance of `Example` has an inaccessible field `Object`. And calling `get` on it replaces the current local value with a new value before returning the new reference. Meaning the old reference is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The second example actually uses more memory than the first example because now each instance of Example must be big enough to store a reference to an Object. I believe you meant to write

```
public class Example {
    public Object obj = new Object();
    public Object foo() {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Now this example has the same memory requirement, but this does have the added benefit of not reallocating an Object every time foo is called. Which will save memory if you call foo() repeatedly.

Comment: It would make more sense if I had included the actual code which is much longer, but the example functions the same but with empty objects in place of the object I am creating.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use jvisualvm or jmc to check both codes.

Run each code with decent and similar scenario. Both tool I mentioned will report memory consumption and garbage collection.